# How To Get JSON Hierarchy Values

Tags: javascript, json

**Hi All, How can I get the id value by using JQuery Mobile**, Thanks

Here I Attach The Code, I just only want to display the id or alert msg for testing, many thanks

```
{"total_rows":7,"offset":0,"rows":[

    {
    "id":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
    "key":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
    "value":{"rev":"1-f59c856e98e1c5f11578562778d8cf3b"}
    },
    {
    "id":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
    "key":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
    "value":{"rev":"1-17731aef6d1d52e0d2ad03e2772d1a0a"} 
    }
                                         ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jsonObj = {
    "total_rows": 7,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
            "key": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
            "value": {
                "rev": "1-f59c856e98e1c5f11578562778d8cf3b"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
            "key": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
            "value": {
                "rev": "1-17731aef6d1d52e0d2ad03e2772d1a0a"
            }
        }
    ]
}

var rowsArray = jsonObj["rows"] //alternatively jsonObj.rows

for (row in rowsArray) {
    console.log(row.id); //alternatively row["id"]
    alert(row.id); //alternatively row["id"]
}
```

Why do you need jQuery mobile for this json?

**EDIT With $.each**

Since you are hell bent on using jQuery

```
var rowsArray = jsonObj["rows"]

$.each(rowsArray, function(i, row) {
    alert(rowsArray[i].id);
});​

$.each(rowsArray, function(i, row) {
    alert(row.id);
});​
```

Comment: But, How if I want to change _for_ to _$.each_ function?

Comment: I've added that in the answer above now. Please learn to simplify. You don't have to use jQuery for everything.

Comment: Yes, It's working, your help is really appreciated. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {
  "total_rows": 7,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [

    {
      "id": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
      "key": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
      "value": {
        "rev": "1-f59c856e98e1c5f11578562778d8cf3b"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
      "key": "637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
      "value": {
        "rev": "1-17731aef6d1d52e0d2ad03e2772d1a0a"
      }
    }
  ]
};

for (id in obj.rows) {

  alert(obj.rows[id].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonObj = '{  
  "total_rows":7,
  "offset":0,
  "rows":[  
    {  
      "id":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
      "key":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618a353a",
      "value":{  
        "rev":"1-f59c856e98e1c5f11578562778d8cf3b"
      }
    },
    {  
      "id":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
      "key":"637184110f5faea091fdbdcf618b85d2",
      "value":{  
        "rev":"1-17731aef6d1d52e0d2ad03e2772d1a0a"
      }
    }
  ]
}';
```

First you can even do this without using jQuery.

Without jQuery:-

```
for(i=0; i< string.rows.length; i++){
 alert(string.rows[i].id);
 alert(string.rows[i].key);
 alert((string.rows[i].value.rev));

}
```

With jQuery

```
$.each(jsonObj, function(key, value){
  console.log(key, value);
})
```